# Proguard rules for a BaseActivity class and its extending classes

Tags: android, inheritance, proguard

I've tried just about everything and can't figure this out.  I have a base class that extends activity with a bunch of shared code in it and 2 classes that extend it.  I was building with the proguard rules I have just fine, but this was without the hierarchy described above.  After refactoring the common code into the base class, I'm getting errors like this:

can't find referenced method 'android.widget.EditText' access$000(com.mypackage.ExtendedClass1)
can't find enclosing method 'void addListeners()' in program class com.mypackage.ExtendedClass1

This base class contains an inner class, and there are references to other libraries, but the problems I'm seeing are nothing to do with those methods.  Are there things I need to watch out for with class hierarchies?  Again, I didn't have these problems until I refactored the common code.  Also, I should note that the base class is abstract!

Please note, I've kept only 4 classes - 1 of which is an inner class in the base class.  My build goes from usually taking around 30 seconds to something that may never end..  I will let it run overnight just to see if it ever returns.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: add rules to `proguard` file to keep all you classes using `-keep`

Comment: Can you please tell me full syntax? I tried that extensively.  The build never ends.

Comment: have you used `proguard` before? i mean are you familiar with using proguard? i will help accordingly.

Comment: It's my first time.  I added some rules after the first 2 lines that got things working before I did the refactoring.  That's why I don't understand why the code in the base class is not recognized by proguard.

Comment: here's the code:  -keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
-dontwarn butterknife.Views$InjectViewProcessor
-dontwarn com.gc.materialdesign.views.**    Sorry for the edits, just can't figure out how to do newlines here

Comment: For `butterknife` visit https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets. For using proguard on your own Java classes visit https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage. Hope this will help.

Comment: It buily finally!  I was doing everything properly. I think I needed to do a clean!